# Unable to execute CLI commands through PHP

Tags: php, apache, ffmpeg

OS: ubuntu 11.10
Webserver: Apache
Code: PHP
I am trying to display the output of command "ffmpeg -i " on the webpage using php. 
Required: The webpage should show the information about video (text).
Whats happening: The webpage shows no text output on running the php code. 
If I was however doing system("ls") the code runs fine and outputs the list of files.
Here's my code

```
<?php
 echo "Details of video file:";
 system('ffmpeg -i /home/atish/Videos/T2V0040006_Angled_ride_720x576i_FLDCMB.avi');
?>
```

The same command works fine on my shell, and my system has ffmpeg installed. Here's a snapshot of executing this command directly on shell:

```
ThinkPad-T420:~/Videos$ ffmpeg -i /home/xx/Videos/T2V0040006_Angled_ride_720x576i_FLDCMB.avi
ffmpeg version git-2012-01-10-7e2ba2d Copyright (c) 2000-2012 the FFmpeg developers
built on Jan 10 2012 12:01:19 with gcc 4.6.1
configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-libfaac --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-    amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libx264 --enable-nonfree --enable-postproc --enable-version3 --enable-x11grab
  libavutil      51. 34.100 / 51. 34.100
  libavcodec     53. 54.100 / 53. 54.100
  libavformat    53. 29.100 / 53. 29.100
  libavdevice    53.  4.100 / 53.  4.100
  libavfilter     2. 58.100 /  2. 58.100
  libswscale      2.  1.100 /  2.  1.100
  libswresample   0.  6.100 /  0.  6.100
  libpostproc    51.  2.100 / 51.  2.100
  Input #0, avi, from '/home/atish/Videos/T2V0040006_Angled_ride_720x576i_FLDCMB.avi':
  Metadata:
  encoder         : Lavf52.23.1
  Duration: 00:00:29.00, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 124422 kb/s
  Stream #0:0: Video: rawvideo (I420 / 0x30323449), yuv420p, 720x576, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
  At least one output file must be specified
```

I have tried appending "DISPLAY=:0" to my command and also done "xhost +" before running php code, but nothing is helping me out.

Thanks.

Comment: What specifically doesn't work? What happens when you execute the PHP code?

Comment: try in console to "su www-data" and see if everything's ok running the cmd again. if not security issue.

Comment: @user247245 it says Authentication failed. It prompted for password and I entered my ubuntu login password. ThinkPad-T420:/var/www$ su www-data
Password: 
su: Authentication failure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [link](http://www.stoimen.com/blog/2011/04/12/an-ffmpeg-question-why-phps-exec-doesnt-return-the-command-output/) explains the how and why. Thanks for the replies folks.

This is the way to get the desired output:

```
echo exec('/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg -i input.mp4 2>&1', $output);  
var_dump($output);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `exec` instead, and pass an output parameter like so

```
$op = array();
exec('ffmpeg -i /home/atish/Videos/T2V0040006_Angled_ride_720x576i_FLDCMB.avi', $op)
```

REF: http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php

Comment: and then I echo $op? I tried this, but all I see as output is this on the webpage: "Array"

Comment: No you will have to do something like... `print_r(implode('\n',$op));` `$op` is an array.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried exec() instead of system()? See [here](http://discussion.dreamhost.com/thread-53586.html) for a discussion of issues with PHP and ffmpeg as well as a method that uses proc_open().